# React + firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I develop and app with create react app (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).

I create a production version with:

```
npm run build
```

This create a folder /build and I upload this with firebase client:

```
firebase deploy
```

All works perfect but in the web app, webpack, show all my code without uglify (see the folder webpack://)

How I can remove this folder from react or firebase hosting? This folder is not in /build folder.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source is shown because you're deploying a `.js.map` file with your project. You can [delete the file](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1004#issuecomment-258249904) after building, or just add it to your Firebase [ignore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying#ignore) so it doesn't deploy.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I decide to use Firebase ignore like this:
  "ignore":[
      "**/*.js.map"
    ]